# Plain HTML/CSS - Multiple files share the same header file (no .php, jquery)

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an exercise project, and the project specifies the following. I have a `menu.html` file and I have two other files: `index.html` and `about.html`. The first one should always be on top while navigating (and scrolling) either the second or the third one, which makes it a navigational menu akin to a header.

I managed to achieve this by using an iframe:

`<iframe src="../html/menu.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe>`

And the menu.html is a list of links:

```
 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" target="_top">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html" target="_top">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

This kind of works, but I have two problems with it.

1. The header with the links is located in the top-left corner, not the centered at the top.
2. I have read that this isn't the best way to do this. I know how to do this for a single html file (by styling the header with css so its position is fixed, with the attributes `top:0` etc). Is there any way I can do something similar to this here? I.e. include the same header for both of the two pages in a different way, but with using only regular html/css?

Comment: It's a shame that `frame` and `frameset` elements have been deprecated otherwise you would have had an easy solution. You should be able to position various `iframe` elements within your page to achieve your desired layout though. 
You don't have a great deal of options if you are not using JavaScript or a backend scripting language like PHP but you may be able to use [server side includes](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/ssi.html) if you have a webserver setup to handle them